# How to get user status(online/away/offline) in real time in QuickBlox Chat Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, quickblox

I implemented group chat functionality using QuickBlox and it works good.
Now I want to get the other users' status like online/away/offline so that I can show the status to user.

I was able to know that QuickBlox for ios provides the delegate for Contact list and I could also track contact list updates in real time by using delegates

```
- (void)chatContactListDidChange:(QBContactList *)contactList{
}
- (void)chatDidReceiveContactItemActivity:(NSUInteger)userID isOnline:(BOOL)isOnline status:(NSString *)status{
}
```

But I can't find any similar thing in QuickBlox package for Xamarin Forms.

Can you please give me any solution for this implementation?
Thanks!

Comment: Set `delaysContentTouches` to `false`.

Comment: @brandonscript I tried to set it to tableview but not work.

Comment: `delaysContentTouches` is part of your parent `UIScrollView` too.  Try setting that to false.  [Here is a tutorial](https://coderwall.com/p/2sid0q/ios-remove-uibutton-touch-delay-inner-uiscrollview) that might point you in the right direction.

Comment: Do you use tap gesture in your code?

Comment: @KamleshShingarakhiya I do no use tap gesture.

Comment: Instead of completely editing an old question and turning it into a new question, you should just ask a new question. This way, the older comments (and possibly answers) won't seem completely off-topic